# How to sort the string items in a custom order in Python

Tags: python, string, list, sorting

I want to sort some items in a specific data structure, But I will try to generalize the problem I am stuck with

My input is a list that contains string items, I am expecting three items as in here, But it won't be necessarily three all the time.
But even though I wanna sort it

My input contain either
`a=['BHR','BHT','BHZ']`
or
`a=['BHN','BHE','BHZ']`
Perhaps Instead of `BH*` we can expect anything but we only focus on the last letter.
either it will be `'Z,R,T'` pair or `'Z,N,E'` pair, the process should be stopped if it is in any other combination.

The output should be in the order of.
`a=['Z','R','T']`
or
`a=['Z','N','R']`
The output should be like this in order-wise even though there is no three items in the list

```
def sorter(a):
    n=len(a)
    for i in np.arange(0,n):
        if (a[i].find('Z') == 1):
            a0=a[i]
            continue
        elif (a[i].find('R') == 1):
            a1=a[i]
            continue
        elif (a[i].find('T') == 1):
            a2=a[i]
            continue
    
    a[0]=a0
    a[1]=a1
    a[2]=a2
```

Can anyone help me to finish this code? or suggest me a simple and effective alternate method?

NB: I would like to save the items in individual variables `a0,a1,a2` and combine them later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sorted`, Sort by `Z, R, T`.

```
a = ['BHR', 'BHT', 'BHZ', "21a"]
a = sorted(a, key=lambda t: "TRZ".find(t[-1]), reverse=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

So you have a ordering of Z, N, R, T in total.

```
a=['BHR','BHT','BHZ']
a.sort(key=lambda t: "ZNRT".find(t[-1]))
```

Comment: I really appreciate your solution. but in my case, I would like to save the items in individual variables `a0,a1,a2` and combine them later